# What is a semantic cognitive map

Tags: terminology, weighted-graphs

Based on: J. P. Carvalho, "On the Semantics and the Use of Fuzzy Cognitive Maps in Social Sciences" (WCCI, 2010 -- [PDF](http://www.inesc-id.pt/pt/indicadores/Ficheiros/6431.pdf)) and Richard Dagan's web page [Cognitive Mapping](http://richarddagan.com/cogmap.php).

A cognitive map consists of nodes representing concepts and ties indicating relationship between the concepts. 
In Carvalho section IV, the semantics is used in perspective of the presented model. Dagan's definition of semantic map is that it is a tree like structure branching from a main concept.

Also, the answer [Are semantic networks ontologies?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9800/are-semantic-networks-ontologies?rq=1) further adds to my confusion as to what is the significant different between cognitive map where nodes are concepts and semantic map where also the nodes are concepts.

I am unable to find significant difference between concept map and semantic map. Can somebody please explain in simple language? Thank you

Comment: Paper2 is just a link to the webpage, but the contents of the webpage contain citations to several papers. Under Sec2 of the webpage, semantic mapping terminology is introduced which I find hard to follow. I find no difference between semantic map and any generic concept map that have been illustrated.

Comment: OK, I've edited the question. A web page isn't a paper and it's confusing to refer to one that way.

Comment: these are terms from psychology from two separate research threads. Degan states that concept maps are a case of cognitive maps. basically after reading Degan, cognitive mapping involves the way an intelligent agent creates a mental map of the external world/reality via their neurobiological systems (neurons/brains). concept maps are created by experts to describe reality based on scientific consensus/ analysis/ understanding. clearly the two are quite similar & can mesh. a possible example of a mismatch would be eg superstitious beliefs or "erroneous thinking" etc.

Comment: @vzn:Thank you for summarizing and extracting the main idea of cognitive map from concept map. So, when does a cognitive map become semantic cognitive map?

Comment: [semantic networks](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_networks) are similar & have a closer connection to CS. clearly a similar concept has been applied in many contexts and fields & nobody seems to have unified it or surveyed it cross-field yet. Degan does a reasonable job also with a section on [semantic mapping](http://richarddagan.com/cogmap.php#semantic) which is like a concept map with personally meaningful definitions/elaborations of its elements. although there might be a way to make more crisper contrasts. suggest this be migrated to [cogsci.se]